# Laravel 5 change password reset link

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, change-password

In the application files, I did not find a blade for this letter. How can I change the link to a normal address, not a localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually laravel generates the password reset url from the `.env` file. So you have to change your `APP_URL` in the .env file to your website url or whatever address you have. And then run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```